# how to manipulate data retrieved from pouchdb

Tags: javascript, node.js, hybrid-mobile-app, pouchdb, nosql

Hi I'm trying to learn pouchDB, i'm facing issue with not being able to manipulate data.

```
db.allDocs({

    include_docs: true
}).then(function(res){
    var r = res.filter(function(){

         });
});
```

I get the following error:

```
       Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: res.filter is not a function(…)
```

I get this error on any array function i'm trying to run on the result set.
Please advice on how to use pouchDB properly to filter the results and get the required document out of it.

Comment: What's typeof `res`? is it an array?

Comment: it's an object, but an object works with array functions right? when i console.log(res) it list's down all the object, but if i console.log(res[0]) it says undefined

Answer (score 0):

Array function can't work with the object.

You can convert `res` into array and after that, you can use `filter` function

```
db.allDocs({

    include_docs: true
}).then(function(res){
    var r = [res].filter(function(){

         });
});
```

It should work.